# Java Midi sequencer timing is off

Tags: java, midi

For the past few days, I've been trying to code a metronome in Java for practice. I have made a simple 4/4 midi beat that the program plays with the use of *javax.sound.midi* library.
My main issue is that the sequencer appears to play the first beat off-time. If I set the sequence to loop, this occurs only the on the first loop. On a side note if I change the track's bpm, it resets after the first loop.
Also, I have tried multiple midi files just in case there was an issue with the midi file that I created but all my tests had the same results.
Here is my code that handles the midi playback:

```
public class MidiHandler 
{
    private Sequencer sequencer;
    private Sequence seq;
    private float newTempoFactor;
    
    public MidiHandler()
    {
        try 
        {
            sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            if (sequencer == null)
            {
                System.err.println("Sequencer not supported");
            }
            sequencer.open();
        } 
        catch (MidiUnavailableException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(MidiHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    
    public void setAudioTrack(String filePath)
    {
        try 
        {
            seq= MidiSystem.getSequence(new File(filePath));
            sequencer.setSequence(seq);
        } 
        catch (InvalidMidiDataException | IOException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(MidiHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    
    public void playTrack(float bpm) throws InterruptedException
    {
        try 
        { 
            seq=editEvents();//editEvents() method pushes all midi events 100 ticks forward
            sequencer.setSequence(seq);
        } 
        catch (InvalidMidiDataException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(MidiHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        sequencer.setLoopCount(Sequencer.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        sequencer.start();
        //sequencer.setTempoInBPM(bpm);
        newTempoFactor=bpm/120;
        sequencer.setTempoFactor(newTempoFactor);//Default tempo is 120bpm --> Tempo factor =1 

         

         sequencer.setLoopStartPoint(100);//Shift the loop start/end by 100 ticks
         sequencer.setLoopEndPoint(seq.getTickLength());
    }    

    public Sequence editEvents() 
    {
        Sequence seq= this.seq;
        try 
        {
            seq = MidiSystem.getSequence(new File("res//myTrack.mid"));
            for (Track track :  seq.getTracks()) 
            {
                for (int i=0; i < track.size(); i++) 
                { 
                    MidiEvent event = track.get(i);
                    event.setTick(event.getTick()+100);  
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (InvalidMidiDataException | IOException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(MidiHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        return seq;
    }

}
```

My main class

```
public class main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        {
            MidiHandler mh = new MidiHandler();
            mh.setAudioTrack("res//myTrack.mid");
            mh.playTrack(120f);
        } 
        catch (SecurityException | InterruptedException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks OK.

The initial beat which is off-timing is usually due to the connected out Midi device (in my case when I use my external USB Midi soundcard). Try with a different MidiDevice if you can.

If you can't, the workaround is to shift all the `MidiEvents` of the created `Sequence` by say 4 beats, then use `Sequencer.setLoopEndPoint(long tick)` and `Sequencer.setLoopStartPoint(long tick)` to make loop start at the new starting point.

For the tempo change after start, it's a JDK bug. The workaround is to call `Sequencer.setTempoInBPM()` right after `Sequencer.start()`.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I managed to overcome the timing issue by shifting all the midi events by 100 ticks forward (seems sufficient). I also managed to fix the tempo issue by calling `sequencer.setTempoFactor()` since `sequencer.setTempoInBPM()` didn't work for me. To calculate the new Tempo Factor, I divided the new value of bpm with 120 (since my midi file has a base tempo of 120). Seems to be working normally.

Comment: Good. If you need to read various Midi files, you'll need to get the tempo by searching  Midi Set Tempo meta message(s) in the read Sequence.